# initializing a deck of cards using ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

im trying to initialize a deck of cards using ArrayList. Basically, my idea is to create new instance of an object each loop where each instance holds two String parameters. However, i keep stuck with first element of suite while the second parameters (rank) goes as expected.

im still confused. how can i pass the desired String in the class while it doesnt appear in the ArrayList.  please help!!

---

```
    package com.Fahad.game;

import com.Fahad.game.deck.DeckOfCards;

public class Game {

    private static DeckOfCards deckOfCards = new DeckOfCards();

    public static void main (String[] args){



        deckOfCards.initialize();



    }

}
```

---

```
    package com.Fahad.game.deck;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class DeckOfCards {

    private Card card;

    private final String[] suite = { "HEART", "DIAMOND", "CLUB", "SPADE" };

    private final String[] rank = { "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "JACK",
            "QUEEN", "KING", "ACE" };

    List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public void initialize() {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < suite.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < rank.length; j++) {

                card = new Card(suite[i], rank[j]);

                deck.add(index, card);

                System.out.println(deck.get(i).getSuite() + " "
                        + deck.get(j).getRank() + " (" + i + "," + j + "):" + index);
                index++;
            }System.out.println("===========================");
        }display();

    }

    public void display(){
        //System.out.println(deck.get(3).getRank() );
        for(int i = 0; i < deck.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(deck.get(i / 8).getSuite() + " || " + deck.get(i % 8).getRank() + "\t(" + i/8+ "," + i%8 + "):" + i);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
    package com.Fahad.game.deck;

public class Card {

    private String suite;
    private  String rank;

    public Card (String suite, String rank){

        this.suite = suite;
        this.rank = rank; 
        System.out.println(getSuite() + "**"+ getRank());
    }

    public String getSuite(){
        return this.suite;
    }

    public String getRank(){
        return this.rank;
    }


}
```

---

i got the following output as a result. please note that the "**" between the suite and the rank is the print method from Card class

```
HEART**SEVEN
HEART SEVEN (0,0):0
HEART**EIGHT
HEART EIGHT (0,1):1
HEART**NINE
HEART NINE (0,2):2
HEART**TEN
HEART TEN (0,3):3
HEART**JACK
HEART JACK (0,4):4
HEART**QUEEN
HEART QUEEN (0,5):5
HEART**KING
HEART KING (0,6):6
HEART**ACE
HEART ACE (0,7):7
===========================
DIAMOND**SEVEN
HEART SEVEN (1,0):8
DIAMOND**EIGHT
HEART EIGHT (1,1):9
DIAMOND**NINE
HEART NINE (1,2):10
DIAMOND**TEN
HEART TEN (1,3):11
DIAMOND**JACK
HEART JACK (1,4):12
DIAMOND**QUEEN
HEART QUEEN (1,5):13
DIAMOND**KING
HEART KING (1,6):14
DIAMOND**ACE
HEART ACE (1,7):15
===========================
CLUB**SEVEN
HEART SEVEN (2,0):16
CLUB**EIGHT
HEART EIGHT (2,1):17
CLUB**NINE
HEART NINE (2,2):18
CLUB**TEN
HEART TEN (2,3):19
CLUB**JACK
HEART JACK (2,4):20
CLUB**QUEEN
HEART QUEEN (2,5):21
CLUB**KING
HEART KING (2,6):22
CLUB**ACE
HEART ACE (2,7):23
===========================
SPADE**SEVEN
HEART SEVEN (3,0):24
SPADE**EIGHT
HEART EIGHT (3,1):25
SPADE**NINE
HEART NINE (3,2):26
SPADE**TEN
HEART TEN (3,3):27
SPADE**JACK
HEART JACK (3,4):28
SPADE**QUEEN
HEART QUEEN (3,5):29
SPADE**KING
HEART KING (3,6):30
SPADE**ACE
HEART ACE (3,7):31
===========================
HEART || SEVEN  (0,0):0
HEART || EIGHT  (0,1):1
HEART || NINE   (0,2):2
HEART || TEN    (0,3):3
HEART || JACK   (0,4):4
HEART || QUEEN  (0,5):5
HEART || KING   (0,6):6
HEART || ACE    (0,7):7
HEART || SEVEN  (1,0):8
HEART || EIGHT  (1,1):9
HEART || NINE   (1,2):10
HEART || TEN    (1,3):11
HEART || JACK   (1,4):12
HEART || QUEEN  (1,5):13
HEART || KING   (1,6):14
HEART || ACE    (1,7):15
HEART || SEVEN  (2,0):16
HEART || EIGHT  (2,1):17
HEART || NINE   (2,2):18
HEART || TEN    (2,3):19
HEART || JACK   (2,4):20
HEART || QUEEN  (2,5):21
HEART || KING   (2,6):22
HEART || ACE    (2,7):23
HEART || SEVEN  (3,0):24
HEART || EIGHT  (3,1):25
HEART || NINE   (3,2):26
HEART || TEN    (3,3):27
HEART || JACK   (3,4):28
HEART || QUEEN  (3,5):29
HEART || KING   (3,6):30
HEART || ACE    (3,7):31
```

Comment: What is the output of your program and how does it differ from what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Rethink your display method. This is really weird:

```
System.out.println(deck.get(i / 8).getSuite() + " || " + deck.get(i % 8).getRank() + "\t(" + i/8+ "," + i%8 + "):" + i);
```

What is it supposed to do? The problem is `i / 8`. You are dividing i by 8, which is for all values other than multiples of 8 zero (integer division!). So in fact you are only getting the first 4 cards from the deck, but each one 8 times.

And as your first 8 cards are all Heart, your output is only Heart ;-)

Comment: Yeah i have noticed that in my inner-mind i thought it was two array i should have treated it as one array. thank you for the enlightenment. :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is with

```
System.out.println( deck.get(i).getSuite() + " "
                    + deck.get(j).getRank() + " (" + i + "," + j + "):" + index);
```

You have an `ArrayList` and `i` is always between `[0,suite.length) = [0,4)`. So when you get the suite you are only getting it from the first 4 cards in the list (and likewise with `j` but you don't see that issue because the rank of card at index `j` is equal to the rank of the card at `i*rank.length + j`). You should have

```
System.out.println( deck.get(index).getSuite() + " "
                    + deck.get(index).getRank() + " (" + i + "," + j + "):" + index);
```

---

Another note, you do not need to keep track of the index when you `add()`, you can simply do `add(card)` and it will add it to the end of the list.

---

As others have noted, your `display` method has similar issues, I just didn't notice when I initially posted.

Comment: i should commit suicide now xD. after getting the first 4 cards the whole time :D.

Comment: i should commit suicide now xD. after getting the first 4 cards the whole time :D. Thank you for the great tips that u taught me.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void display(){
        //System.out.println(deck.get(3).getRank() );
        for(int i = 0; i < deck.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(deck.get(i / 8).getSuite() + " || " + deck.get(i % 8).getRank() + "\t(" + i/8+ "," + i%8 + "):" + i);
        }
    }
```

In this method your `deck.get(i/8)` is only grabbing the suit of the 0th element, 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th elements added to the deck (which will always be heart).  I would simply call `deck.get(i)` instead.

I would also remove this line from the initialize function:

```
System.out.println(deck.get(i).getSuite() + " "
                        + deck.get(j).getRank() + " (" + i + "," + j + "):" + index);
```

Comment: it had been fixed. Thank you for the help. didn't realized that until now